# Update the database from a collection ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, database, mvvm, observablecollection

I am currently working with EnterpriseLibrary 5.0 and MVVM:

I have an `ObservableCollection ListCategories<Category>` property binded to an editable ComboBox (I can add/delete/edit categories):

I have the following code:

```
public ObservableCollection<Category> ListCategories
        {
            get
            {
                return listCategories;
            }

            set
            {
                listCategories = value;
            }
        }
    var categories = sdb.ExecuteSprocAccessor <Category> ("Get_Categories_List");

                 ListCategories = categories.ToObservableCollection <Category>();
```

My question:

After all changes made in the collection, how to update back the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to have a DB Access layer behind the Repository pattern of:

```
public interface IRepository<T>
{
   IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
   T GetById(int id);
   void Save(T saveThis);
   void Delete(T deleteThis);
}
```

then implement this with your domain type Category (I'm assuming that's a domain type and not a type generated by an ORM.

```
public interface ICategoryRepository : IRepository<Category>
{
    // add any methods that are needed to act on this specific repo
}
```

then set the dependency in the ViewModel to this ICategoryRepository;

```
private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepo;

public ViewModel(ICategoryRepository categoryRepo)
{
    _categoryRepo = categoryRepo;
}
```

Then act on this dependency from your ViewModel, your ViewModel SHOULD NOT be calling a database directly which is what you seem to be implying.

your code:

```
sdb.ExecuteSprocAccessor <Category> ("Get_Categories_List");
```

should reside in the GetAll() of the repository.  Move it out of the ViewModel.

your setting of the observable collection should be done in the ctr:

```
ListCategories = categories.ToObservableCollection <Category>();
```

to this:

```
public ViewModel(ICategoryRepository categoryRepo)
{
    _categoryRepo = categoryRepo;
    var categories = _categoryRepo.GetAll();
    ListCategories = categories.ToObservableCollection <Category>();
}
```

Comment: thanks Mark,Normally I wont do call the database from the ViewModel, I was just focusing on this problem,I wanted to have everything under eyes. What I was trying to say is to do that update with filling  a DataSet and then Update Database via DataAdapter if it's possible of course

Comment: This explanation is great @MarkW, and to the point. How should adding an item to the collection/repository work? I assume it's costly to keep calling GetAll() to refresh the view, so can we just add manually to the Repository and then the ObservableCollection?